# Fermion zero modes in a monopole background field in a theory with a fermion triplet

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, magnetic-monopoles

I'm working on the following problem, I am not quite sure how to proceed.

Consider a fermion isotriplet $\psi ^a$ for $a=1,2,3$. And

$$S_{\psi} = \int d^4x \ (i\bar{\psi}^a \gamma^{\mu} (D_{\mu} \psi)^a - f\epsilon^{abc}\bar{\psi}^a\psi^b \phi^c) $$
$$ (D_{\mu} \psi)^a$ = \partial_{\mu}\psi^a + g \epsilon^{abc}A^a_{\mu}\psi^c$$

The problem, which comes from Rubakov, asks to find the analogue of the conserved fermion angular momentum in
the monopole background field.

Also, only for fermions with minimal momentum, that there exist fermion zero modes in the monopole field (eigenstates
of the Dirac Hamiltonian with zero energy), and the number of those.